# How to get rid of "C++ exception specification ignored" warning

Tags: c++, qt, warnings, exception-specification

I recently got a dll that has been implemented by others. I have to use it in my application. In the header file of their class they have the function declaration

```
void func1() throw (CCustomException);
```

Now when i compile it am getting the warning,

> C++ exception specification ignored
>   except to indicate a function is not
>   _declspec(nothrow)

I read the [MSDN - Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa28fef8%28VS.80%29.aspx) but couldn't understand it clearly. Also, I don't want to disable the warning just because it is showing up. I want to know what I am doing wrong instead of disabling it.

I thought my function, *say* `myfunc()` accessing that `func1()` from the dll doesn't have that Exception specification list. Hence I tried having the corresponding exception specification list in my function too as,

```
void myfunc1() throw (CCustomException);
```

But I am still getting the warning. What is that warning is all about and how to get rid of it? I am using Qt 4.5 in Windows XP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, it is a non-answer, but I would [throw away the exception specification and never use it again](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm).

EDIT: I read too fast, and I didn't see you did not write the class yourself. Best way to get rid of warnings in msvc is via #pragma warning(push) followed by #pragma warning(disable:xxxx) where xxxx is the warning code :

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER 
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:xxxx)
#endif 

...

#ifdef _MSC_VER 
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

EDIT: It is perfectly safe to disable the warning. Exception specifications are evil, and the compiler is only telling you it is disabling them for you. Even if it breaks the standard.

Comment: It sounds like it's compiling as C++0x, in which exception specifications like this are deprecated, rather than C++03. There may be a compiler option to specify that you want '03, or just to reenable exception specifications if you want other '0x features.

Comment: @Alexandre C, Ya i agree with disabling and all, but what the warning is all about?? Why it is occurring and what's the rationale behind it?? I just wanted to know these..

Comment: @liaK: see the link posted by Alexandre.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Why do you think it's compiling as C++0x? The Visual Studio compiler has _always_ ignored non-empty exception specifications; its been this way since long before deprecation was proposed for C++0x.

Comment: @Charles: Because I know nothing about Visual Studio. I should have read the linked MSDN page before commenting; it's simply warning about its failure to implement the current standard.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Fair enough, it explains your comment. I think if you do use Visual Studio it's fairly common knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You might try playing with preprocessor:

```
#ifdef _SOME_MSVC_DEFINE
#  define _throw(foo)
#else
#  define _throw(foo) throw(foo)
#endif

void myfunc1() _throw (CCustomException);
```

Or, try to disable that warning in Visual Studio.